# How the CMS content area gets the widget short-codes? How to decoded the short-code in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How the CMS content area gets the widget short-codes? How to decode the short code.

```
[content] => <style>#html-body [data-pb-style=CC0XS9Y]{justify-content:flex-start;display:flex;flex-direction:column;background-position:left top;background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:scroll}</style><div data-content-type="row" data-appearance="contained" data-element="main"><div data-enable-parallax="0" data-parallax-speed="0.5" data-background-images="{}" data-background-type="image" data-video-loop="true" data-video-play-only-visible="true" data-video-lazy-load="true" data-video-fallback-src="" data-element="inner" data-pb-style="CC0XS9Y"><div data-content-type="products" data-appearance="grid" data-element="main">{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" anchor_text="" id_path="" show_pager="0" products_count="5" condition_option="category_ids" condition_option_value="675" type_name="Catalog Products List" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`aggregator`:`all`,`new_child`:``,`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`value`:`1`^],`1--1`:^[`operator`:`==`,`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`value`:`675`^]^]" sort_order="position"}}</div></div></div>
```

**In the above content get multiple {{widget}} and make it as array.**

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, all "short-codes" (also called `directive`) have their own method to process it with the following naming convention :

- `<directiveName>Directive` will process `{{<directiveName> ...}}` strings
- `widgetDirective` will process `{{widget ...}}` strings
- `transDirective` will process `{{trans "foo"}}` strings
- and so on...

In your case, searching for `widgetDirective` will lead you to the following class : `\Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter`.

You can use this class, using the `filter` method, giving your string in the parameter, which will be parsed.

Comment: I added above class in my controller and  call filter method but getting error Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml' in module: 'Magento_CatalogWidget' block's name: 'product\productslist_0'

Comment: The `Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml` template (used as parameter in your "content" only exists on the frontend area. If you are trying to render it on the Admin area; you will need to add it in the adminhtml templates.

Comment: I added the file but the widget product SKU not render. when I am saving the cms page that time I am calling one event in that event on the post data I am preparing the array of  all widget shorts code

Comment: filter() method renders only HTML not returning the array of code

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question. What do you want your array to look like (using your example) ?